# tomcat7 installation fails with error code 1

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dpkg, tomcat7

I am trying to install `tomcat7` on my machine but I get the following error.

```
Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up authbind (2.1.1+nmu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to uninstall tomcat7 with the below command and reinstall the same but with no solution.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove tomcat7
```

It removes the tomcat7 but reinstalling I get the same error.

Please suggest what's wrong here.

Comment: What is the `journalctl -xe` output?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution if you can start installation from scratch:

```
sudo aptitude purge tomcat7
whereis tomcat7
sudo rm -rf /etc/tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo aptitude install tomcat7
```

Comment: I still get the same error. does this has anything to do with Ubuntu version? I am running 16.04

Comment: Can you post an output of the following command : sudo dpkg -l | grep tomcat.

Comment: [Please](http://pastebin.com/uBLEDPWN) check...

Comment: May be this link http://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/730-community-tomcat-deployment-ubuntu-help-required may help you.